# как отследить нажатие кнопки "отмена" у TimePickerDialog

Tags: android, kotlin

мне нужно закрыть фрагмент, если у TimePickerDialog нажали кнопку отмена.

```
override fun onStart() {
  super.onStart()
  val send = parentFragment as GetTime
  val timeSetListener = TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener { _, hour, minute ->
      send.getTime(hour, minute)
      dismiss()
  }
  val timePickerDialog = TimePickerDialog(context, timeSetListener, 0, 0, true)
  timePickerDialog.show()
}

interface GetTime{
    fun getTime (hour: Int, minute: Int)
}
```

я не знаю как определить нажатие "отмена"

Comment: Так же как и у любого другого Dialog: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog#setOnCancelListener(android.content.DialogInterface.OnCancelListener)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
timePickerDialog.setOnDismissListener{
    //TODO
}
```